# Accordion needs to scroll to the top upon opening Javascript

Tags: javascript, accordion, scrollto

I'm familiar with jQuery, but not so much with Javascript. I have an accordion function in javascript in which I need the accordion panel to scroll to the top of the open panel on the click. Right now it scrolls to the bottom of the panel when opened. Here's the click function I'm working with...Thanks in advance!

```
myAPP.AccordionPanel = function ( headingEl, panelHolder, index ) {
// The AccordionPanel Class controls each of the collapsable panels spawned from Accordion Class
var self = this;

this.panelHolder = panelHolder;
this.index = index;
this.headingEl = headingEl; // this is the clickable heading
this.contentEl = headingEl.nextElementSibling;//headingEl.querySelector( this.panelHolder.panelSelectors['content'] ); 
this.isSelected = false;

this.setupAccessibility();

this.headingEl.addEventListener( "click", function () {

    if (self.isSelected){
        self.unselect(); // already open, presume user wants it closed
    }
    else {
        self.panelHolder.resetPanels(); // close all panels
        self.select(); // then open desired panel        
    }

    return false;
});

return this;
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the element you are clicking, you could call a function like below to scroll to it. if the thing you are clicking is not that, you will need a reference.

function liberated from here - http://itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

```
function elmYPosition(eID) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
  var y = elm.offsetTop;
  var node = elm;
  while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
      node = node.offsetParent;
      y += node.offsetTop;
  } return y;
}

scrollTo(0, elmYPosition('idstring'));

//html

<div id="idstring">scroll to me</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I added a little to the offset to keep it from running under my sticky navigation and it worked great. Thanks!